How to place the contents in the box on the same line of the title?
I want to place the contents in the box on the same line of the title "Workshops and". The codes I wrote is as follows:
\documentclass[letterpaper,10.9pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tabular}{@{} l l}

\large{\textbf{Workshops and}}  \\
\large{\textbf{Conferences}} & \parbox[t]{5.0in}{2022 Summer Doctoral Workshop in Country 1, 2023 Winter Doctoral Workshop in Country 2, 2021 Summer School in Country 1, 2021 International Economics Workshop in Country 1, 2023 International Economics Workshop in Country 2, 2021 Conferences in Country 1, 2022 Conferences in Country 1, 2022 Conferences in Country 2, 2023 Conferences in Country 1, 2023 Conferences in Country 2, 2023 Conferences in Country 3, 2024 Conferences in Country 3.}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}

The output looks like the following:

The content "2022 Summer Doctoral Workshop..." is on the line of "Conferences". What I want is: to put "2022 Summer Doctoral Workshop..." and "Workshops and" on the same line. That is, to raise up the contents in the box to the line of "Workshops and".
I have a proposal for this problem. I changed the codes a little bit, and the revised codes is as follows:
\documentclass[letterpaper,10.9pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tabular}{@{} l l}

\large{\textbf{Workshops and}}  
& \parbox[t]{5.0in}{2022 Summer Doctoral Workshop in Country 1, 2023 Winter Doctoral Workshop in Country 2, 2021 Summer School in Country 1, 2021 International Economics Workshop in Country 1, 2023 International Economics Workshop in Country 2, 2021 Conferences in Country 1, 2022 Conferences in Country 1, 2022 Conferences in Country 2, 2023 Conferences in Country 1, 2023 Conferences in Country 2, 2023 Conferences in Country 3, 2024 Conferences in Country 3.} \\
\large{\textbf{Conferences}} 

\end{tabular}

\end{document} 

Then the output is the following:

Now my question is: how to place "Conferences" just under "Workshops and"? I want to delete the blank lines between "Workshops and" and "Conferences".
Any suggestions and comments are welcome.

Off-topic: \large is a toggle not a command with argument.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Are the red horizontal lines part of the expected output? Without a minimal working example I would guess, that you want to either use, e.g., package multirow for the second column or want to use p column for both columns, or just want to move some text form the parbox to the first row (after an additional &).

@cabohah Thanks for your comments. I will revise the codes to make it compilable. Yes, I want to raise the contents in the parbox up to the line of the title "Workshops and".

@cabohah I have revised the codes. Now you can run it.

There are several suggestions to change the table, e.g., using multirow for the second column or move some text from the second row of the second columns to the first row, or use two p-type columns for both rows (or p + X):
\documentclass[letterpaper,10.9pt,oneside]{article}% See also the note at the end of the answer.
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{mwe}% for the dummy text used
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\large\bfseries\raggedright}p{1.5in}X}
  Workshop and Conferences&
  2022 Summer Doctoral Workshop
  in Country 1, 2023 Winter Doctoral Workshop in Country 2, 2021 Summer School
  in Country 1, 2021 International Economics Workshop in Country 1, 2023
  International Economics Workshop in Country 2, 2021 Conferences in Country
  1, 2022 Conferences in Country 1, 2022 Conferences in Country 2, 2023
  Conferences in Country 1, 2023 Conferences in Country 2, 2023 Conferences in
  Country 3, 2024 Conferences in Country 3.
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\lipsum

\end{document}

But in your case, I just would suggest to not use a tabular but two \parboxes side by side:
\documentclass[letterpaper,10.9pt,oneside]{article}% See also the note at the end of the answer.
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{mwe}% for the dummy text used
\begin{document}
\noindent
\parbox[t]{\dimeval{\textwidth-5.1in}}{\raggedright\large\bfseries
  Workshop and Conferences
}\hfill
\parbox[t]{5.0in}{2022 Summer Doctoral Workshop
  in Country 1, 2023 Winter Doctoral Workshop in Country 2, 2021 Summer School in Country 1, 2021 International Economics Workshop in Country 1, 2023 International Economics Workshop in Country 2, 2021 Conferences in Country 1, 2022 Conferences in Country 1, 2022 Conferences in Country 2, 2023 Conferences in Country 1, 2023 Conferences in Country 2, 2023 Conferences in Country 3, 2024 Conferences in Country 3.}

\bigskip
\lipsum

\end{document}


Another suggestion would be to use a description list with multiline label using package enumitem:
\documentclass[letterpaper,10.9pt,oneside]{article}% See also the note at the end of the answer.
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{mwe}% for the dummy text used
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=1.5in,font=\large\bfseries]
\item[Workshop and Conferences]
2022 Summer Doctoral Workshop
  in Country 1, 2023 Winter Doctoral Workshop in Country 2, 2021 Summer School
  in Country 1, 2021 International Economics Workshop in Country 1, 2023
  International Economics Workshop in Country 2, 2021 Conferences in Country
  1, 2022 Conferences in Country 1, 2022 Conferences in Country 2, 2023
  Conferences in Country 1, 2023 Conferences in Country 2, 2023 Conferences in
  Country 3, 2024 Conferences in Country 3.
\end{description}

\bigskip
\lipsum

\end{document}


Additional note: You are using option 10.9pt (and I've not changed this). But article does not support such an option:
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [10.9pt].

So the font size of your document is still the default 10pt. If you want sizes like 10.9pt see: How to specify font size less than 10pt (or more than 12pt)? Even if the question itself might suggest otherwise, it also answers how to set font sizes such as 10.9pt.

Many thanks! The codes I wrote here is part of my CV. So I would like to keep the formats unchanged (i.e., still use the tabular and \parbox).

Thanks for your comments. I have a new proposal for this problem. Pls see the updated post. My question is: for the updated codes, how to delete the blank lines between "Workshops and" and "Conferences"? I think it is not difficult. There should be some command to realize this. Do you know how to do?

@YaHe You should not add another question to your question. If you have a follow-up question please ask a new one. However, this is the same issue. If you don't want a new table row, don't start a new table row. Use either p (or X) columns as I've shown in my first example or use parboxes as I've shown in my second example or use a list as I've shown in my third example. I would prefer the list solution, because lists also support page breaks and your problem is more a list with short topics (aka items) and optional longer content than a table.

Define a suitable command for the job. It will make it easy to change your mind about the typesetting.
This implementation uses two parboxes side-by-side, with 1em (in the main font size) separation.
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}

\newlength{\cvwidth}
\setlength{\cvwidth}{5in} % change it to suit
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % indent not needed in a CV

\newcommand{\cventry}[2]{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimeval{\textwidth-1em-\cvwidth}}{\large\bfseries\raggedright#1}%
  \hfill
  \parbox[t]{\cvwidth}{#2}
  \par
  \addvspace{\medskipamount}%
}

\begin{document}

\cventry{Workshops and Conferences}{
  Summer Doctoral Workshop in Country 1, 2023 Winter Doctoral Workshop 
  in Country 2, 2021 Summer School in Country 1, 2021 International
  Economics Workshop in Country 1, 2023 International Economics Workshop 
  in Country 2, 2021 Conferences in Country 1, 2022 Conferences in Country 1, 
  2022 Conferences in Country 2, 2023 Conferences in Country 1, 
  2023 Conferences in Country 2, 2023 Conferences in Country 3,
  2024 Conferences in Country 3.
}

\cventry{Bells, whistles and things}{
  Something here that doesn't span two lines
}

\cventry{Bells, whistles and things}{
  Something here that doesn't span two lines
}

\end{document}


For instance, just removing \large will get

that seems to me a lot more elegant.

Many thanks for your answer. I have a proposal for this problem. Pls see the updated post. My question is: for the updated codes I wrote, how to delete the blank lines between "Workshops and" and "Conferences"? I think it is not difficult compared to the previous question. There should be some command to realize this. Do you know how to do?

@YaHe It cannot work.
